# Microsoft Access: Remove duplicate from Table and replace with Random list from table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a  table in access with two fields: state and city. The state is unique and the city should be the same.

I have a table that shows duplicate states with the same city. I want to make the city that is duplicate to be random within the state. I have another table that calls out the cities in the states.

I currently have:

```
State   
Washington  Seattle
Washington  Seattle
```

I want it to be:

```
Washington  Seattle
Washington  Bellevue
```

How do i remove the duplicate city and replace one of it with a random city  in the state like the example above?

Assuming that i have a separate table that I can create to call out all the cities in a state.

I have no idea how to tackle this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if there are more records for a state than there are cities available?

Comment: @invent - animate, I dont think that will happen because every day we will only show a maximum amount of 20 states. Every two days we want the city to be unique and not used. After the two days are over, the city can be use again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this (based on your comment) is to add two fields to your city table. Call it something like [Used] and [DateUsed]. use some type of random function to pick your cities. As you use the city, change the [used] field to true and put today's date in the [Dateused] field. Use a query to pull only the cities that are marked False. You can run a daily query, any [Dateused] that is older than 2 days you can clear the true flag from the [used] field and clear the [DateUsed] field.

```
dim db as dao.databse
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim sql as string
dim x as integer

x = 0
set db = currentdb
Do While X < 20
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [tblcities] WHERE [Used] = false AND stateID = " & some value for stateID
    set rs = db.openrecordset(SQL,dbopenDynaset)
    if rs.recordcount > 0
        rs.movefirst
        do while not rs.eof
            if randomfunction() = true  //just an example, you'll have to come up with the random function on your own.
                SQL = "UPDATE [tblCities] SET [Used] = True, [DateUsed] = DATE() WHERE StateID = " & Some Value for StateID & " AND CityName = '" & rs!cityName & "'"
                docmd.RunQuery SQL
                break do
            end if
        rs.movenext
        loop
    end if
    set rs = nothing
    x = x + 1
loop

set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```

(rough code, I'm sure there are lost of little typo or syntax error, but this not meant to be a complete example, only to point you in a direction.)